# When passing enum into a WebService the SOAP not saves its original values

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, enums, webmethod

When passing enum into a WebService the SOAP XML is not saving its original values.

**SERVER SIDE**

```
public enum MyEnum {  Val1 = 10,  Val2 = 32,  Val3 = 45 }

[WebMethod]
public MyEnum DoSomthing()
{
...
}
```

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
public enum MyEnum {  Val1 = 0,  Val2 = 1,  Val3 = 2 }
```

All i need is to save the enum original values because they have a meaning in the client code.

Comment: What do you mean by "not saving its original values"? SOAP passes enums by name only, the value is lost. Use a data contract library containing the enums and their values, and use that library from service and client.

Comment: enum int value on the client side has changed from 10,32,45 to 0,1,2

Comment: @shay CodeCaster explained exactly why this is happening and posted a solution for that. Why such a weird setup in the first place?

Comment: Because these numbers are needed.